Does a lightbox feature for images improve accessibility?
Consider a website that has accessibility (a11y) as a priority and implements it accordingly.
The site has quite a few images that contain detailed information (e.g., a screenshot of a historical document such as the United States Declaration of Independence), but due to the layout of the site, the images are not very large.
So, even if someone is not visually impaired, it may be difficult to identify the content/details in some of the images due to their size (not their quality).
To improve the a11y of these images, I first thought of implementing a lightbox feature (similar to what Wikipedia has implemented, as you can see from the link above).
However, I was concerned that having an <a> element around each image might be confusing to some users, especially those navigating with assistive technologies such as screen readers.

To summarize my question, are lightbox links considered accessible and best practice on the web when implemented properly?
Is there any research or data on this topic? Is it sufficient to have appropriate alt text and rely on browser/system tools such as Zoom?

Maybe this question would be more suited for the User Experience Stack Exchange

Having a link around each image is totally ok. The performance of the site would suffer tremendously, if each image would be included in full resolution. You should provide an easy way to retrieve the original image file, so that users can make the best of their assistive technologies in use. And Wikipedias Lightbox does not suffice. Think more of the in-browser PDF viewer. It provides zoom as well, which Wikipedia doesn’t. Even browser zoom is ignored for the size of the image.

Thanks for your input. Maybe you're right, some parts of my question relate to UX, but I was thinking more of a technical approach, such as whether lots of lightbox links have an impact on performance and how it's handled by assistive technologies through the browser accessibility tree or whether it's just distracting. There are probably better implementations of a lightbox, but I don't think Wikipedia's is that poor. It's keyboard-accessible, it provides information about the image like a description and copyright, and it provides a way to enter full-screen or turn the feature off completely.
